# Rds File size increasing after reading

Tags: r

I've a large dataset (over 1 GB), which I converted into Rds file. After conversion, the size reduces to around 12 MB. But when I'm reading the Rds file back into R, the size is increasing to over 1 GB again.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It is because Rds is a compressed file format. See the helpfiles `?saveRDS`.

Comment: @jsb: Thanks for your quick answer!